# Custom Installer needs to detect .NET Framework

Tags: c#, .net

I am writing a custom installer in C#.

Can you tell me an easy way to check if the machine has .NET version installed [even 2.0].

In cases where it is not installed, my app doesn't even start.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSDN has a [blog post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/astebner/updated-sample-code-to-detect-the-net-framework-3-0) with sample code to detect if .NET 3 is installed.

[Edit: As mentioned by [Stephen Clearly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263693/stephen-cleary), the author of the blog post also **released a [tool](https://web.archive.org/web/20160224223636/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/astebner/archive/2008/10/13/8999004.aspx) that can be easily wrapped in a custom installer (and supports all .NET versions)**]

Otherwise:

You could always use the file system and check in the **%systemroot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework** folder.

This will tell you if the following release versions of .NET are installed

- v3.5
- v3.0
- v2.0.50727
- v1.1.4322
- v1.0.3705

Comment: The writer of that blog post also released a [tool](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2008/10/13/8999004.aspx) that can be easily wrapped in a custom installer (and supports all .NET versions).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is your *custom installer*, but you  could use a [Setup and Deployment  Project](https://vijirajkumar.blogspot.com/2010/03/create-setup-and-deployment-project.html) in Visual Studio where you can define [.NET Framework launch condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/cschotte/vs2008-launch-conditions-and-prerequisites).